# SQL MIN() smaller/greater not working properly

Tags: sql

I have this Data in DB

```
CREATE TABLE Stu_Table
(
    Stu_Id VARCHAR(2),
    Stu_Name VARCHAR(15), 
    Stu_Class VARCHAR(10),
    sub_id VARCHAR(2),
    marks VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (1, 'Komal', 10, 1, 45);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (2, 'Ajay', 10, 1, 56);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (3, 'Rakesh', 10, 1, 67);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (1, 'Komal', 10, 2, 47);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (2, 'Ajay', 10, 2, 53);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (3, 'Rakesh', 10, 2, 57);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (1, 'Komal', 10, 3, 45);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (2, 'Ajay', 10, 3, 56);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (3, 'Rakesh', 10, 3, 67);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (1, 'Komal', 10, 4, 65);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (2, 'Ajay', 10, 4, 56);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (3, 'Rakesh', 10, 4, 37);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (1, 'Komal', 10, 5, 65);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (2, 'Ajay', 10, 5, 46);
INSERT INTO Stu_Table VALUES (3, 'Rakesh', 10, 5, 63);
```

And I'm doing this query on this data.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Stu_Id,
        MIN(marks) AS mini,
        AVG(marks) AS per
    FROM stu_table
    GROUP BY stu_id
    HAVING MIN(marks) > 45
);
```

And I'm getting this:

```
Stu_Id| mini  |  per
   1  |  45   |  53.4
   2  |  46   |  53.4
   3  |  37   |  58.2
```

I don't understand why I still see **Stu_Id** `1` with min(mark)=45 when I clearly have this `HAVING min(marks)>45` in my query.

[Runnable Demo](http://ideone.com/h97DqT)

**FIX:**
Thanks to @sybkar and @Martin Smith!

I set the marks type as a string.
It's should be INT...

Thanks guys!
Working perfect!

```
create table Stu_Table(Stu_Id INT(2), Stu_Name varchar(15), 
Stu_Class  varchar(10),sub_id INT(2),marks INT(3));<--INT!!!
```

Comment: First off, what DBMS are you using?  Second, why are you storing numbers in a VARCHAR field?

Comment: `AVG(marks)` would be invalid in SQL Server. How do you average a string?

Comment: Damn.. I didn't see this coming... I guess this is the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Mind you the `AVG` results look as though it implicitly casts to `numeric`. And the string datatype doesn't explain why it shows a result with `45` when you say `>45`

Comment: BTW. fill free to create an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: What RDBMS are you actually using? Your ideone demo does only return a single row not the three you state in the question.

Comment: And this is goo cos the two other have a min mark smaller than 45, I just wanted to check something about using min() i Having clause.. And I don't really have more than 1 table as you see in the create above..

Comment: @Ofear - But the entire question is "why am I getting these results"? And the demo link doesn't produce these results.

Comment: oh.. sorry.. I fixed the result.. I will change it back to the wrong results :)  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand why I still see **Stu_Id** `1` with min(mark)=45
>   when I clearly have this `HAVING min(marks)>45` in my query.

You don't. Or at the least the demo you have provided doesn't.

In general any weird results that you are getting will be because `marks` is being stored as a string so `MIN(marks)` will be bringing back the earliest in alphabetical order though.

For example `HAVING MIN(marks) > 45` will also bring back `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` and `9`